# How to make it so windows doesn't show the volume/new track information?

Tags: windows, audio, dialog

Windows added a new feature that I'm certain seemed like a good idea the time -- whenever you adjust the volume or change the track this little dialog with what you're listening to and at what volume pops up. Problem is, I'm finding a lot of times this dialog is in the way, and if heaven forbid I try and interact with anything behind it, it stays up even longer. Is there any way to disable this functionality?

[image]

Comment: For anyone wondering why it's such a pain, I have the second scroll wheel on my mouse assigned to the volume. I change it constantly depending on how loud my meeting/music/presentation/training video is.

Answer (score 2):

Windows 10 does not give an option for hiding this annoyance.

That's why one user has written the
[HideVolumeOSD](http://wordpress.venturi.de/?p=1)
utility. This very small utility can auto-start with Windows and let you hide or
unhide the Volume OSD from the traybar.

[image]

I tried it, but needed to use HideVolumeOSD version 1.2 to make it work
on the current Windows 10 version.